# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p + k^p}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

A couple of series I've been trying to solve:

$$1. \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p + k^p}\\ 2. \text { For which $x$ does the following converge: }\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1} {n^x} \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {2^x} + \dotsb +\frac {1} {n^x}\right )$$

I note for #2 that $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x n^ {x-1} } \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {1} {n^x} \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {2^x} + \dotsb +\frac {1} {n^x}\right ) \leq \frac1{n^{x-1}},$$

which shows that it diverges for $x\leq 1$ and converges for $x>2$. So $(1,2]$ is really the only question.

For #1 I note that $$\int_1^N \frac {x^{p-1}} {N^p + x^p}dx = \ln{\left ( \frac {2N^p} {N^p +1} \right )} \overset{n\to \infty}{\to} \ln{2}.$$

If I could show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(  \int_1^n \frac {x^{p-1}} {N^p + x^p}dx -  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p + k^p} \right) < \infty,$$

I think that would be enough, but why would that be true? (Setting up integrals and switching orders hasn't seemed to work.)

Comment: how $k$ is linked with the second question?

Comment: No relation. They are completely separate questions!

Comment: In the second problem replace the index $k$ by $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second, note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^x}$$

is always $\geqslant 1$, and for $x > 1$, it is bounded by $\zeta(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use Riemann sum for the first series.

**Added:**

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p + k^p}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k/n)^{p-1}}{1 + (k/n)^p} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^p}dx $$

Comment: And the value of the limit is $____$.

Comment: @Did $p^{-1}\log 2$

Comment: @Did: At least the OP has to do some work! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks for evaluating the integral.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p + k^p}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\left(\frac kn\right)^{p-1}}{1+\left(\frac kn\right)^{p}}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^p}dx$$

Comment: Great! That settles the first one.

Comment: And the value of the limit is $____$.

Comment: @Did 2. (assuming $p>0$)

Comment: @EricAuld The value of the limit is not $2$, except if $p=\frac12\log2$.

Comment: Well, then maybe this deserves a new answer. I, for one, cannot find an easy way to do this integral, and WA cannot do it.

Comment: @DonAntonio The integral is $p^{-1}\log 2$. It follows from $$\dfrac{d}{dx}p^{-1}\log(1+x^p)=\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^p}$$

Comment: Thanks, that I didn't see.

Comment: Whoops, messed that one up. Thanks guys